# How to stop control border padding increase when scaling an object on FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How to stop control border padding increase when scaling an object on FabricJS?

I have a rectangle

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
});

// create a rectangle object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 200,
  top: 185,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  padding: 0
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wwexsh1f/2/

[Scaled Rectangle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEuPz.png)

When I scale my rectangle with **mouse** or **rect.scaleTo** function the control border padding also increases although padding set to **0**.

How to stop padding increase on scaling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set strokeWidth = 0;

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 200,
  top: 185,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  padding: 0,
  strokeWidth : 0
});
```

It scales with the object

Comment: Thank you very much @Filipe Roberto